# Cohomology of $\operatorname{SO}(p,q;\mathbb{Z})$ with $p=3,q=19$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, cohomology, group-cohomology, symmetric-spaces, arithmetic-groups

I would like to understand the topology of the moduli space of Einstein orbifold metrics on the $K3$-surface. It is known that this space is given by the bi-quotient $SO(3,19;\mathbb{Z})\setminus SO(3,19)/SO(3)\times SO(19)$ and I know that this has the same rational cohomology as $SO(3,19;\mathbb{Z})$. Is there anything known about these groups? Unfortunately my knowledge on arithmetic groups is very limited.

Comment: $H^1$ vanishes, http://people.uleth.ca/~dave.morris/talks/H1Vanish.pdf

Comment: Above degree 1 where property (T) answers the question one can usually prove vainshing results for lattices in Lie groups using representation theory. In "low" degrees (I hope at least for $H^2$) you can probably extract an answer from the book of Borel and Wallach : https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1721403 (this is not a very convenient reference as given but giving a precise answer would take time so it'll have to do at present). Be careful that your lattice is not cocompact which complicates matters a bit (see last chapter in loc. cit.).